# Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM + Dynamic ProxyPassMatch

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, apache2

Expect result:

If I go to `http://foo.local/index.php`, file `/var/www/html/foo/index.php` will be executed.

It will be similar if I go to `http://bar.local/index.php`, `/var/www/html/bar/index.php` will be executed.

Here are my configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/

    <IfModule proxy_module>
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://localhost:9000/var/www/html/$1 (this  line works in normal virtualhost)
        ProxyRemoteMatch ^([^.]+).*/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://localhost:9000/var/www/html/$1/$2
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

For now, this is working well for static files like .html.
But it will print .php files instead of executing them.

Please advise, thank you.

PS: If I use mod_php instead of php-fpm, it would be easier. But for learning purpose, I really want to go the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my own solution (use RewriteRule with [P] flag instead of ProxyPass):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/%1/$1 [P]
    #<IfModule proxy_module>
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
        #ProxyRemoteMatch ^([^.]+).*/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1/$2
    #</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```